# Pagination links in codeigniter 2 went to empty result

Tags: php, pagination, codeigniter-2

I tried to create pagination in search result. I got whole search result and correct number of pagination links, but when tried to go to next page search result went blank. 1st page should be fine. But it dosen't shows any error.

Here is the code:

Controller function

```
public function staffsearch() {
        if ($this->session->userdata('logged_in') == FALSE) {
            $this->index();
        } else {
            $data['action'] = site_url('user/staffsearch/');
            $search_by = $this->input->post('search_by');
            $keyword = $this->input->post('keyword');

            if (!empty($search_by) && !empty($keyword)) {
                $uri_segment = 3;
                $offset = $this->uri->segment($uri_segment);
                $staff_details = $this->User_Model->get_staff_search_result($search_by, $keyword, $this->limit, $offset)->result();
                $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM `staff` WHERE `" . $search_by . "` LIKE '%" . $keyword . "%'");
                $count = $query->num_rows();

                $this->load->library('pagination');
                $config['base_url'] = site_url('user/staffsearch/');
                $config['total_rows'] = $count;
                $config['per_page'] = $this->limit;
                $config['uri_segment'] = $uri_segment;
                $this->pagination->initialize($config);
                $data['pagination'] = $this->pagination->create_links();


                //$staff_details = $this->User_Model->get_staff_search_result($search_by, $keyword)->result();
                $this->load->library('table');
                $this->table->set_empty('&nbsp;');
                $this->table->set_heading('S/No', 'Image', 'Name', 'Office', 'Phone');
                $i = 0;
                foreach ($staff_details as $staff) {
                    if ($staff->Office) {
                        $id = $staff->Office;
                        $staff_office = $this->User_Model->get_office_by_id($id)->row();
                        $office = $staff_office->building . ' ' . $staff_office->level . '-' . $staff_office->unit;
                    } else {
                        $office = '';
                    }
                    if ($staff->Photo_small == '') {
                        $pic = 'unavailable.jpg';
                    } else {
                        $pic = $staff->Photo_small;
                    }
                    $this->table->add_row(++$i, '<image src="' . base_url() . 'people/' . $pic . '" width="50" height="50">', anchor('user/staffdetails/' . $staff->people_id, $staff->Name), $office, $staff->Phone);
                }
                $data['title'] = 'Search Result';
                $data['table'] = $this->table->generate();
            }
            $this->load->view('search_staff', $data);
        }
    }
```

Model function:

```
function get_staff_search_result($fiels, $key,$limit = 10, $offset = 0) {
        if ($fiels == 'Name') {
            $this->db->like('Name', $key);
        } elseif ($fiels == 'Staffnumber') {
            $this->db->like('Name', $key);
        } else {
            $this->db->like('Appointment', $key);
        }
        $this->db->order_by('Name', 'asc');
        return $this->db->get($this->tbl_staff,$limit, $offset);
    }
```

View:

```
<div>
    <h2><?php if (isset($title)) { echo $title;} ?></h2>
    <?php if (isset($table)) { echo $table; } ?>
    <?php if (isset($pagination)) { echo $pagination;} ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The links created by the pagination class won't contain the 'search_by' and 'keyword' criteria and they certainly won't be in the post variables as when you click a page link you are doing an HTTP GET.

You need to think about either storing the criteria in somewhere like the user's session so that it can be reused for each page request or look to use the Pagination library from CodeIgniter 3 which supports adding items (such as your two search terms) as query string parameters which you could then also check for.

Details about the CodeIgniter 3 Pagination class can be found [here](https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/blob/develop/system/libraries/Pagination.php).

Not tried this myself but you should also be able to amend the URL for the pagination links so they read:

```
site_url('user/staffsearch/') . $search_by .'/' . $keyword;
```

You could then read the individual URL segments to retrieve the search terms.